# Comparing industrial vs. off-the-shelf analog input

Tags: arduino, analog, raspberry-pi, input

Industrial controls are expensive and my company current spends a great deal of money installing them to monitor some rudimentary signals on equipment.

For instance, we're trying to monitor:

- temperature from some thermocouples (https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/991/25545991/att_70599/v1/et200s_2ai_i_4wire_st_manual_en-US.pdf)
- vibration (https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/033/25546033/att_105646/v1/et200s_2ai_tc_hf_manual_en-US.pdf)

Temperature we're monitoring to about the nearest degree (not much precision required) whereas vibration (inches/second) needs more precision (standard value may be something like 0.0048 ips with alarms triggered at 0.400ips).

My question is this: would off-the-shelf hardware like the Arduino/rPI/etc. have the precision to measure these same sorts of signals for a radically lower price point?

Comment: rPI certainly not - it has no analog reading capabilities of its own. It would be entirely down to what ADC system you build for it.

Comment: Question is, do they have the same reliability as the Siemens devices? What is the cost per hour if your sensor stops working? If a production line is stopped, for example, it could be very expensive.

Comment: Rather than speculating, just take two "competing" components and compare their datasheets.

Comment: There is a reason why companies spend the money on industrial standard solutions. By the time you added ruggedness, galvanic isolation and proper housings to the toy stuff you will have spent far more than buying the proper stuff in the first place unless your time is worth nothing. If you can hack together a proof-of-concept, on the other hand, it can be valuable.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, good points but by having more affordable solution you can instrument far more than with more conventional methods. Also, leveraging, say, .NET means you can deploy easily like a real software application. That's hard to do with PLCs when you have hundreds in the field. That means faster turnaround for new features and easier development for more complicated logic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally it's not the ADC capability that you're paying for.  At the end of the day the actual ADC will be working the same way whether you have an Arduino or an expensive PLC.

What you are paying for is what is around the ADC:

- Stable / filtered reference voltages
- Low noise instrumentation amplification
- (sometimes, depending on application) galvanic isolation
- (sometimes, depending on application) environmental isolation
- Longevity.
- Standards.

Most of which you could theoretically achieve with an Arduino (or a Raspberry Pi if you added your own ADC system to it since it doesn't have one of its own), but by the time you have developed the system to give the same kind of performance and stability as the expensive PLC you'll probably find that the costs amount to considerably more than the PLCs.

And then when your system goes wrong, who do you turn to?   When your boss says "It's not working" you would then have to find out why and get it working again.  Or you can turn to Siemens and say "It's not working" and they can fix it for you.  If you have left the company, who is going to keep your system running for the company?

Many environments and industries have strict regulations around what equipment can be used.  Getting your equipment certified for use in, say, a petrochemical environment costs vast amounts of money.  Probably more than the total you have ever spent, or are likely to spend, on PLCs etc.

Comment: In addition to the above, another MAJOR point in any plant is to use standardized components that can be worked on by just about any qualified ET or even Electrician.  Once you start adding customized doodads, you are asking for trouble when there is a failure at 2 in the morning.  Especially if the doodad creator is no longer in the same position, or even with the company.  Sometimes also, regulatory concerns dictate what equipment you can use.  You probably cant make a safety rated device without a huge lump of cash behind you.

Comment: Thankfully, these systems are not essential to production. Instead, they're for gathering data (environmental, generally) to track where we can make improvements in things like gas consumption and electrical consumption. That means, if we can drop the price 70%, we can instrument far more than we do today and have more thorough insight into our facility. If it breaks...get a new one. It's not hard if the new device is only $100-200, but these IO modules along are 3-4 times that, let alone the whole rack.